# New to tikz, how to align three arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, graphs

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}

\tikzstyle{intt}=[draw,text centered,minimum size=6em,text width=5.25cm,text height=0.34cm]
\tikzstyle{intl}=[draw,text centered,minimum size=2em,text width=2.75cm,text height=0.34cm]
\tikzstyle{int}=[draw,minimum size=2.5em,text centered,text width=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{intg}=[draw,minimum size=3em,text centered,text width=6.cm]
\tikzstyle{sum}=[draw,shape=circle,inner sep=2pt,text centered,node distance=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{summ}=[drawshape=circle,inner sep=4pt,text centered,node distance=3.cm]

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      >=latex',
      auto
    ] \node [intg] (ka)  {Quantum Transport};
      \node [intg] (kp)[node distance=2cm,below of=ka]  {Semi-classical transport};
      \node [int]  (ki1) [node distance=1.5cm and -1cm,below left=of kp] {Ballistic};
      \node [int]  (ki2) [node distance=1.5cm and -1cm,below right=of kp] {Diffusive};
      \node [intg] (kb)[node distance=2cm,below of=ki2]  {Boltzmann Transport Equation};
      \node [int]  (kb1) [node distance=1.5cm and -1cm,below left=of kb] {Relaxation Time Approximation};
      \node [intg] (kb2)[node distance=2cm,below of=kb]  {Drift-Diffusion type};
      \node [int]  (kb3) [node distance=1.5cm and -1cm,below right=of kb] {Hydrodynamic-type};
     
     

      \draw[->] (ka) -- (kp);
      \draw[->] (kp) -- ($(kp.south)+(0,-0.75)$) -| (ki1) node[above,pos=0.25] {No Scattering} ;
      \draw[->] (kp) -- ($(kp.south)+(0,-0.75)$) -| (ki2) node[above,pos=0.25] {Scattering present};
      \draw[->] (ki2) -- (kb);
 \draw[->] (kb) -- ($(kb.south)+(0,-0.75)$) -| (kb1) node[above,pos=0.25] {} ;
 \draw[->] (kb) -- (kb2);
      \draw[->] (kb) -- ($(kb.south)+(0,-0.75)$) -|(kb3) node[above,pos=0.25] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this
[image]

My question is, you see the three nodes at the very bottom? How do I align them? I tried different positions for the middle box but it doesn't seem to work. Also for some reason the middle box is bigger than the two around it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you want such starting points of the final arrows, but now it is easy to improve.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}

\tikzstyle{intt}=[draw,text centered,minimum size=6em,text width=5.25cm,text height=0.34cm]
\tikzstyle{intl}=[draw,text centered,minimum size=2em,text width=2.75cm,text height=0.34cm]
\tikzstyle{int}=[draw,minimum size=2.5em,text centered,text width=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{intg}=[draw,minimum size=3em,text centered,text width=6.cm]
\tikzstyle{sum}=[draw,shape=circle,inner sep=2pt,text centered,node distance=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{summ}=[drawshape=circle,inner sep=4pt,text centered,node distance=3.cm]

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      >=latex',
      auto
    ] \node [intg] (ka)  {Quantum Transport};
      \node [intg] (kp)[node distance=2cm,below of=ka]  {Semi-classical transport};
      \node [int]  (ki1) [node distance=1.5cm and -1cm,below left=of kp] {Ballistic};
      \node [int]  (ki2) [node distance=1.5cm and -1cm,below right=of kp] {Diffusive};
      \node [intg] (kb)[node distance=2cm,below of=ki2]  {Boltzmann Transport Equation};
%      \node [int]  (kb1) [node distance=1.5cm and -1cm,below left=of kb] {Relaxation Time Approximation};
 %     \node [intg] (kb2)[node distance=2cm,below of=kb]  {Drift-Diffusion type};
%      \node [int]  (kb3) [node distance=1.5cm and -1cm,below right=of kb] {Hydrodynamic-type};
  \node [int] (kb2)[node distance=2cm,below of=kb]  {Drift-Diffusion type};
 \node [int]  (kb1) [node distance=0.5cm, left=of kb2] {Relaxation Time Approximation};    
        \node [int]  (kb3) [node distance=0.5cm, right=of kb2] {Hydrodynamic-type};   

      \draw[->] (ka) -- (kp);
      \draw[->] (kp) -- ($(kp.south)+(0,-0.75)$) -| (ki1) node[above,pos=0.25] {No Scattering} ;
      \draw[->] (kp) -- ($(kp.south)+(0,-0.75)$) -| (ki2) node[above,pos=0.25] {Scattering present};
      \draw[->] (ki2) -- (kb);
 \draw[->] (kb) -- ($(kb.south)+(0,-0.75)$) -| (kb1) node[above,pos=0.25] {} ;
 \draw[->] (kb) -- (kb2);
      \draw[->] (kb) -- ($(kb.south)+(0,-0.75)$) -|(kb3) node[above,pos=0.25] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but how do I make the bottom 3 arrows to be of the same size as the rest?

Comment: @Indeterminate It is my question: where should they start? At the bottom of `Bolzmann transport equation`, at some point below it or somewhere else?

Comment: I guess this looks okay too, not sure how to make it more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: @Indeterminate Changing -0.75 to -0.25 in the last lines gives a pretty good result: `\draw[->] (kb) -- ($(kb.south)+(0,-.25)$) -| (kb1) node[above,pos=0.25] {} ;
 \draw[->] (kb) -- (kb2);
      \draw[->] (kb) -- ($(kb.south)+(0,-0.25)$) -|(kb3) node[above,pos=0.25] {};`

Comment: Thanks it looks much better now.